# Chisel 3.4.2 syncmem and a black box. No memory replacement with --repl-seq-mem option

Tags: chisel, firrtl

I run MemtestInst code with --repl-seq-mem option. It has a black box and a SyncReadMem. No memory replacement happens and config file is empty.
If I comment MyBBox line or use older Chisel, replacement works.
Chisel that works:

```
val defaultVersions = Map(
  "chisel3" -> "3.2.5",
  "chisel-iotesters" -> "1.3.5"
  )
```

This one fails (so far the latest one):

```
val defaultVersions = Map(
  "chisel3" -> "3.4.2",
  "chisel-iotesters" -> "1.5.2"
  )
```

Scala code:

```
package explore

import chisel3._
import chisel3.util._

class MemoryInst extends Module {
  val bitsDatNb = 64
  val bitsAddrNb = 9

  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val wAddr = Input(UInt(bitsAddrNb.W))
    val wData = Input(UInt(bitsDatNb.W))
    val wEn   = Input(Bool())
    val rAddr = Input(UInt(bitsAddrNb.W))
    val rEn   = Input(Bool())
    val rData = Output(UInt(bitsDatNb.W))
  })

  val myBbox = Module( new MyBBox())
  val memFile = SyncReadMem(1<<bitsAddrNb, UInt(bitsDatNb.W))

  when(io.wEn) {
    memFile.write(io.wAddr, io.wData)
  }
  io.rData := memFile.read(io.rAddr, io.rEn)
}
class MyBBox() extends BlackBox(
  Map(
    "LEN_BITS" -> 8,
    "ADDR_BITS" -> 10,
    "DATA_BITS" -> 64)) with HasBlackBoxResource {

  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val clock = Input(Clock())
    val reset = Input(Bool())
  })
  setResource("/verilog/someverilog.v")
}

object MemtestInst extends App {
  chisel3.Driver.execute(args, () => new MemoryInst)
}
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This works for me: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/LWc1VQbPQhC6ILLKsZJlSg, can you make a Github (or other) repo with a reproducible example?

Comment: IMHO : That exact code is reproducible in chipyard. Just have to provide verilog resource file name (an empty src/main/resources/verilog/someverilog.v works) and don't  comment it in scala code above.

Comment: Created repo with example https://github.com/aasorokighb/firrtl_mem_map_with_blackbox_bug

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Chisel version 3.4.0

I can confirm that the code similar you have works with memory mapping without blackbox and not with it. I suggest the following adding

```
import chisel3.stage.{ChiselStage, ChiselGeneratorAnnotation}
```

and changing

```
object MemtestInst extends App {
  chisel3.Driver.execute(args, () => new MemoryInst)
}
```

to

```
object MemtestInst extends App {
    val annos = Seq(ChiselGeneratorAnnotation(() => 
        new MemoryInst()
    ))
    (new ChiselStage).execute(args, annos)
}
```

I think `chisel3.Driver.execute` is  with 3.4 and later.